# Reshape a feature by tracing another edge without using topology in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, editing

In ArcMap I could select a feature to edit, select "reshape" and then turn on tracing to follow a line I want to align with, but in ArcGIS Pro I can't find this functionality, only the "align edge" tool for topology.  I tried using this tool but it keeps giving me failure errors so I just want to trace like before.

Is there a way to use the old trace ability to reshape?

Comment: What are the precise and detailed steps that you perform in ArcMap, which you say work, and then what are the precise and detailed steps that you have tried in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it "reShape" under "Tools" in the "Edit" menu?
[image]

After selecting a feature, you can change its shape by tracing in ArcMap in the same way by selecting the trace tool on the editing toolbar.
You can also set shortcut keys from "Customize Ribbon".

---

About supplements

[image]

I think it's the button that appears when you turn on "Show editing toolbar on map" and use "reshape", but I'm sorry if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, that was it, however my toolbar showing the trace option was not displaying in order to select that over straight-line digitizing.  Once I sorted out how to get that toolbar displaying it works similar to ArcMap, thanks!